Non-Blocking OpenSSL server using epoll
I have been trying to get this to work for a while now and have run out of ideas. The idea is to have a non-blocking server, implementing openssl, and using epoll to pick up on incoming events.
Code (chaotic sketch to see basic functionality):
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <asm-generic/socket.h>
#include <openssl/crypto.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>

#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#define PORT 8443
#define BUFFERSIZE 4096
#define MAXEVENTS 16

#define TESTSTRING "<html><p>I am a message</p></html>"

int init(int * sfd);
void runServer(int sfd);
void eventLoop(struct epoll_event * ev, int sfd, int poll);

typedef struct {
    int fd;
    SSL * ssl;
} NetworkUser;

typedef struct {
    char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
    uint16_t messageLength;

    NetworkUser * netUsr;
} NetworkPackage;

SSL_CTX * ctx;
SSL * serverSSL;

int main() {
    printf("Loading Server!\n");

    int sfd;
    if(!init(&sfd))
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    runServer(sfd);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int init(int * sfd) {
    SSL_library_init();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLS_method());
    if(!SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version(ctx, TLS1_2_VERSION)) {
        printf("Unable to set CTX version!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if(SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, "test-cert.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) {
        printf("Unable to load cert!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if(SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, "test-key.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) {
        printf("Unable to load private key!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if(!SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx)) {
        printf("Key don't match!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    serverSSL = SSL_new(ctx);
    if(!serverSSL) {
        printf("Could not create Server CTX!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    SSL_set_accept_state(serverSSL);
    printf("Keys loaded\n");

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    *sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(*sfd == -1) {
        printf("Unable to start socket!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    int opt = 1;
    setsockopt(*sfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt, sizeof(opt));
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if(bind(*sfd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1) {
        printf("Unable to bind port!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if(listen(*sfd, SOMAXCONN) == -1) {
        printf("Unable to listen!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("Server loaded\n");
    return 1;
}

void runServer(int sfd) {
    int poll = epoll_create1(0);
    if(poll == -1) {
        printf("Can't create poll!\n");
        return;
    }
    struct epoll_event ev;
    ev.data.fd = sfd;
    ev.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
    epoll_ctl(poll, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sfd, &ev);
    printf("Starting loop...\n");
    while(1)
        eventLoop(&ev, sfd, poll);
}

void eventLoop(struct epoll_event * ev, int sfd, int poll) {
        struct epoll_event events[MAXEVENTS];
    int nr = epoll_wait(poll, events, MAXEVENTS, -1);
    for(int i = 0; i < nr; i++) {
        if(events[i].data.fd == sfd) {
            printf("New connection\n");
            int con;
            con = accept4(sfd, NULL , NULL, SOCK_NONBLOCK);
            if(con < 0) {
                printf("Connection error\n");
                continue;
            }
            NetworkUser * usr = malloc(sizeof(*usr));
            usr->fd = con;
            usr->ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
            if(!usr->ssl) {
                close(con);
                free(usr);
                printf("Unable to accept new client connection - Unable to init SSL\n");
                ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
                break;      
            }
            if(SSL_set_fd(usr->ssl, con) <= 0) {
                ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
                close(con);
                SSL_free(usr->ssl);
                free(usr);
                printf("Unable to accept new client connection - Unable to set fd to SSL\n");
                break;
            }
            SSL_set_accept_state(usr->ssl);
            printf("Attempt to accept\n");
            while((SSL_accept(usr->ssl)) <= 0) 
                sleep(1);
            printf("Accepted\n");
            if(SSL_write(usr->ssl, TESTSTRING, strlen(TESTSTRING)) <= 0) {
                printf("Couldn't write!\n");
            }
            printf("Add to list\n");
            (*ev).data.ptr = usr;
            epoll_ctl(poll, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, con, ev);
            printf("Successfully registered!");
        }
    }
}

Its just being compiled using
gcc -Wall -g -o nettest main.c -lssl -lcrypto

It is just a sketch and only implements for when a new client connects. During the tests I have encountered a range of issues, the one I am asking about right now is the fact that I don't seem to get the message send to me. When running the server and connecting to it using my browser, I can see how the client is being registered but my browser just keeps loading the site as if it obtains nothing. In a previous setup my browser did load the message though (but other things didn't work). I also thing my question is more broad, as an outline, how do I create such a listener? (I'm trying to not implement the BIO api).

If you connect to the server with a browser, then the browser will expect that after the TLS handshake is completed, the server will send an HTTP response.  You are sending bare HTML, instead.  I'm not sure that this fully explains your problem, but it is certainly a problem.

did something like that a while ago using only "select"
